# How to make a font-face render bigger?

Tags: html, css, fonts, internationalization, font-face

Using CSS, I am using this line to style a bilingual element:

```
 font-family:persianFont, englishFont;
```

Both persianFont and englishFont are defined with `@font-face`. The problem is that characters with englishFont are shown a little bigger, because the font has been created to be so. A sample sentence would be rendered like this:

> BIG_ENGLISH_WORDS_small_persian_BIG_ENGLISH_AGAIN...

So, my question is how can I make persianFont a little bigger (**make it have a bigger scale**), so that a line of bilingual persian-english sentence is shown correctly both in the same size? Is this possible at all? Is there any other solution?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post some HTML so that we can see what is accessible to CSS?

Comment: This is not the matter of HTML elements. I have a string in an element. string is unified, means persian and english are all together in one place and not separated.

Comment: So how does your CSS declaration work? How is each font applied?

Comment: I use `*{font-family:persianFont, englishFont;}` , If the character is in persianFont font then persianFont will be applied, else englishFont will be applied. Thats how bilingual fonts are matched.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest creating a span separately and increasing the font-size as an ideal solution.

If I assume your `body` is having a default `font-size` of `12px`, then proportionately, you need to increase the span size.

**For Instance,**

```
span{
     font-size:14px;
}
```

**From your example, for Instance,**

```
<p>BIG_ENGLISH_WORDS_<span>small_persian</span>_BIG_ENGLISH_AGAIN...</p>
```

Hope this helps.

*PS: You can do the same by creating a class or an id selector.*

Comment: This is not possible for me and is not my solution

Comment: Any reasons why you cannot make the above changes? As that is providing the solution? - @MostafaShahverdy

Comment: I get text from users, and they type Persian and English all together.

Comment: Plus I want to know if it is solvable only by HTML and CSS, and not any extra PHP processing

Answer (score 1):

I finally understood what you meant. I think you should look at the `unicode-range` CSS property. It may not have adequate browser support yet but that also depends on your target audience. Chrome has prett ygood support at least.

I remember reading about it on 24ways.org. Here is an exercpt from an article by **Drew McLellan** (http://24ways.org/2011/creating-custom-font-stacks-with-unicode-range/)

> The `unicode-range` descriptor is designed to help when using fonts that
>   don’t have full coverage of the characters used in a page. By adding a
>   unicode-range property to a `@font-face` rule it is possible to specify
>   the range of characters the font covers.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: BBCBengali;
    src: url(fonts/BBCBengali.ttf) format("opentype");
    unicode-range: U+00-FF;
}
```

> In this example, the font is to be used for characters in the range of
>   `U+00` to `U+FF` which runs from the unexciting control characters at the
>   start of the Unicode table (symbols like the exclamation mark start at
>   `U+21`) right through to ÿ at `U+FF` – the extent of the Basic Latin
>   character range.
>
> **By adding multiple `@font-face` rules for the same family but with
>   different ranges, you can build up complete coverage of the characters
>   your page uses by using different fonts.**

There is also a great [article by **Richard Ishida**](http://rishida.net/blog/?p=760)) about `unicode-range` accompanied by a test case which I have posted on [**JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/p55rC/).

**[edit]**

So your next step is to identify the Unicode code points corresponding the the persian language and make a CSS rule, as described above, targeting those code-points and changing the font size accordingly.

Comment: Yes, I am doing this. In fact this is the default behavior! My problem is the scale of "BBCBengali". I need to have "BBCBengali" bigger or smaller than another font-face in the same family.

Comment: Do you mean that you are already using `unicode-range`? It would be good if you could post a URL to a page I can see to better understand.

Comment: No, this is the default behavior. Because Persian font are not covering all unicode ranges and they cover only persian characters.

Comment: I will post a link as soon as I could upload anything